# how to calculate percentage for each cell and replace tha value with result(%) using pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is the sample example:

```
input:
sub del wait 
12  55  11   
13  33  71
```

ex:
1st row:
del=55*100/12=458.33
wait=11*100/12=91.66

2nd row:
del=33*100/13=253.3
wait=71*100/13=546.01

**final output should be:**

```
sub del    wait     
12  458.33  91.66   
13  253.3   546.01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select both columns, multiple by `100` and divide by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html), then assign columns back with [`DataFrame.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) if necessary:

```
df[['del','wait']] = df[['del','wait']].mul(100).div(df['sub'], axis=0).round(2)
print (df)
   sub     del    wait
0   12  458.33   91.67
1   13  253.85  546.15
```

Or divide by numpy array created by [`Series.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) with shape (N x 1) for divide per rows:

```
df[['del','wait']] = (df[['del','wait']] * 100 / df['sub'].to_numpy()[:, None]).round(2)
print (df)
   sub         del        wait
0   12  458.333333   91.666667
1   13  253.846154  546.153846
```